# Mongo : what is the type in model of an id - string or ObejctId?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to add to my Comment schema the id of the user who made the comment.
Is the proper way to do it:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var commentSchema = new Schema({
    title       : String,
    userId       : String //or
    userId: ObjectId // or
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Trying to understand mongoose schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a reference to the user who made the comment, the correct way to do it is to use the `ObjectId` field with a `ref` option:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
const commentSchema = new Schema({
    title       : String,
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

When you save a comment, you can set the `user` field to the _id of the user who made the comment. Then when you retrieve a comment, you can use Mongoose's `populate()` method to populate the user field with the corresponding user document.

For example, with `populate`:

```
Comment.findOne({ _id: commentId })
    .populate('user')
    .exec((err, comment) => {
        // `comment.user` will now be the user document
    });
```

Or without:

```
Comment.findOne({ _id: commentId })
    .exec((err, comment) => {
        // `comment.user` will now be the user id
    });
```

Comment: thank you and lets say i will not need to get the user ever, I only will ever want to get the userId from the comment. Would I still use the ObjectId field with a ref option?

Comment: In this case you can use the first or second options from your question. I'd personally still use it as reference for possible future needs.